# Get QuerySet from ForeignKey in Django

Tags: jquery, django, django-models

I have two models in Django:

```
class Category(models.Model)
   ....

class Article(models.Model)
   category=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
```

I would like to get some categories with some filter, and all the articles of this Category in the same Query.

I try with annotate, but I do not know how is the correct syntax.

```
categories = Category.objets.filter(whatever='whatever').annotate('article')
```

Comment: `category_instance.article_set` will give you all the articles of a given category. Note: this will perform multiple queries to the database (one for each time you use this), You can use `prefetch_related` to perform all these queries together if needed. (Not possible to get a Many relation in one database query, it is how the ORM is built)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `prefetch_related` and from the `Article` model you'd use `select_related`.

From the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related);

> `prefetch_related`, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using select_related, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one relationships that are supported by `select_related`. It also supports prefetching of `GenericRelation` and `GenericForeignKey`, however, it must be restricted to a homogeneous set of results. For example, prefetching objects referenced by a `GenericForeignKey` is only supported if the query is restricted to one `ContentType`.

This example would be like your model, I have a `Team` object which has a FK on the `Entry` model;

```py
        team = Team.objects.prefetch_related(
            'entry_set'
        ).filter(id=team_id).first()
```

Unless you set a `related_name` on the FK field, django will make the related set in the format of model name in lower case followed by `_set`. So your `Category` will have an `article_set` for the related articles.

And as I said, `select_realted` will do the reverse. Take this model for example;

```py
class SocialAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(allauth.app_settings.USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can get the related object of the FK relationship in the same query by doing;

```py
social_account = SocialAccount.objects.select_related(
    'user'
).get(uid=user_id)
```

Comment: You should specify that `prefetch_related` will perform multiple queries to the database.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat good point. Added a quote from the docs to explain how it works.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you just need to use `prefetch_related`, and since you're in a reverse foreign key query you need to add _set to the Article model.

`categories = Category.objets.prefetch_related('article_set').filter(whatever='whatever')`